# UpdateSeriesAsync Doesn't work in Blazor-ApexCharts

Tags: blazor, apexcharts

I have list named 'listTAPivotAll'. I want to update chart depending on user decision. Its dynamic. If user wants to display realtime or historical values, I'm assign relative list to that list.

I'm using UpdateSeriesAsync to update the chart however it doesn't updated, old values remains. However if i re-call that function twice, it updates.

What could be the reason?

```
private async Task getRealtime(){
    ... load listTAPivotHistoric
    listTAPivotAll = listTAPivotRealtime;
    await chart.UpdateSeriesAsync();
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

}

private async Task getHistoric(){
    ... load listTAPivotHistoric
    listTAPivotAll = listTAPivotHistoric;
    await chart.UpdateSeriesAsync();
    await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
}
```